# Microsoft Outlook Actionable Message API call not working

Tags: outlook, office365connectors, actionable-notification

I am trying to send an actionable messages in outlook. The message card is rendered in the mail. But the service call(call to an API on click of Submit button from the actionable message) is failing only for few users in the organization.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in Outlook desktop that breaks actionable messages for some users. The fix will be shipped with July 2019 update.

Do the users see the same issue in Outlook Web? If so, please contact onboardoam at microsoft.com and provide the affected user email addresses.